# how to work without with navigation controller

Tags: iphone

hi before i never use navigation controller, 
can i use navigation controller like this

consider in my app there is **three view** (ie main view, first view, second view)
on main view, **two UIButton's with button action** to move into first view and second view respectively
and to go back to main view, i have to place navigation controller(like back button wiht title) on first view and second view(note:- not navigation controller on main view)

i want to place navigation controller on first view and second view for back to main view 
**note**:- on my **main view no navigation controller**, navigation controller will be on first and second view used as back buttons and title
**can you guide me to the solve this problem**

Answer (score 3):

@nandakishore i suggest you to choose the navigation based app in the beginning because you need navigation controller in most of your views(first view and second view)

And you hide the navigation controller when main view didLoad and unhide that when view will dissappear

eg:- In mainview.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

now by doing this u will not get navigation controller in mainview but get that in other two views

Hope this may help u....Good luck!!!