# hide navigation bar in selected view in navigationbased application-iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, navigationbar

I am working on application, I had made application navigationbased. I want to hide navigation bar from the selected view only how can i do that?
i used following code but it hides the bar from whole application
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

If there is any way please let me know..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to accept your previous answers.then more people will help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide navigation bar in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028074/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

on view which you want navigation controller use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
```

this in viewWillAppear

And

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
```

in viewWillDisappear method of same view

Answer (score 1):

In the selectedView hide the navigation controller when main view didLoad and unhide that when view will dissappear

eg:- In selectedView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

now by doing this u will not get navigation controller in selectedView but get that in other views...For more corcern try to take help from already asked [how to work without with navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543490/how-to-work-without-with-navigation-controller/4543681#4543681)

Hope this may help u....Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code,

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;`

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to write below code in that controller in which you want to hide your Navigation bar...

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

and you have to write below code in which you want to show Navigation bar...

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=NO;

write both code in respective viewWillAppear ...