# How to hide navigation bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, hidden

Currently i am working in iPhone app, I have two screen like A and B, A has no navigation bar, but B has navigation bar. so i set like this.

Class A:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"A";
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Class B:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"B";
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}

-(void)Previousscreen
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

then i run the application, When i go to previous class like B to A at the time blue color show in B class below attached screen shot for your reference. How to fix this issue? please help me

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO]; set this line in viewWillAppear also.

Comment: Which color you want to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use this code:

`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES]`

in ***- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated*** or later in the view lifecycle in both classes. [Avoid doing this in ***- (void)viewDidLoad***.]

The trick here is in using the *setNavigationBarHidden:**animated**:* method (in place of the simpler *setNavigationBarHidden:* method). This will ensure your UI issue goes away and also any positional issues due to it.

P.S. Check the value of *self.navigationController.**navigationBarHidden*** (instead of *self.navigationController.**navigationBar.hidden***) if you need to check if your navigation bar is hidden, at some point, in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Set it in class B

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: becoz class b navigation bar also hide

Comment: You want it in B, then set NO.

Comment: i read your question again, you want to hide on class A not on B, even when they come back.

Comment: yes its correct, but when the user go to previous class B to A, at the time blue color image show in fraction of second, so how to fix this issues? show in screen shot above

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `navigationBarHidden:` in `viewWillDisAppear` of **class B**

in **class B**

```
-(void)viewWillDisAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just try setting the above code in class B and remove the other settings in class A of navigationBar to be set to YES/NO

Comment: I tried this but, when i go to previous Class A navigation bar shownn it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a behavior when you are hiding and showing the navigation bar dynamically as you are pushing controllers is supported.

Simple solution - hide the animation bar of the `UINavigationController` and if you want to show it on some controller, just add a `UINavigationBar` to it.

Comment: Can you please give any example for this

Answer (score 0):

Use below line to hide `navigationBar`in `viewWillAppear:` method -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: I found that I had problems using that method- 

If I used the interactive swipe from the left to go back a page from the second to the first screen, but released it early (without completing the swipe), the navigation controller would get "stuck" displaying the second screens title and button bars when I moved onto a third screen.

The solution was to use setNavigationBarHidden:animated:, like so:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`


This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay for `Hide` and `Unhide` the `navigationBar`. The problem is that you're hiding `Class A`'s `navigationBar` in `viewWillAppear:` which is called just before appearing the view so before loading the `Class A` view `navigationBar` is being hidden each time.
And if we talk about your blue color i think it is your `window` color. Because after hidden the `navigationBar` there will be a space above your `self.view` which height is **44.0**. So there are three options to fixed it.

- Hide `Class A`'s `navigationBar` in `Class A`'s `viewDidAppear:` method.
- Set your `window` color what you want to show.
- You can add an image to `window` background in which at top of image make a `navigationBar` same as `Class B`'s `navigationBar` so when the original `navigationBar` will be hide it will see.

Comment: i want when the user go to previous class B to A, at the time blue color image show in fraction of second, so how to fix this issues?

Comment: Which color you want to see at that time ?

Comment: I think that can not be set directly that fraction of seconds will appear.

Comment: Please see above screen shots, the blue color shown in right half of the screen.

Comment: @Minu - I have seen, I asked what do you want i mean what color should be here instead of blue?

Comment: YES, Because it is not your code problem. It is how objective-c works.
Well you can do one thing add an image to `window` background in which at top of image make a `navigationBar` like `Class B` so when the original `navigationBar`will be hide it will show :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18464/discussion-between-vakul-saini-and-minu)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to solve this recently and I found that it was necessary to call `setNavigationBarHidden:NO` immediately after `pushViewController:` and `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` immediately after `popViewController:`, with animated YES in each call.

So, when pushing:

```
[nc pushViewController:classBView animated:YES]
[nc setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]
```

and when popping:

```
[nc popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
[nc setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]
```

But in my case, while I could do pushing as above, I didn't want to alter my **class B** and instead wanted it to not know of care that the navigation bar wasn't previously hidden (since its not my code). Also, that view gets popped using the normal Back button, there was no explicit call to `popViewControllerAnimated:`. What was going to work best in my code was to make my **class A** be the `UINavigationController` delegate and hide the toolbar on a delegate method call when the pop occurs.

Unfortunately I found that the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods weren't too helpful, `willShowViewController` & `didShowViewController` are called indistinguishably when pushing my **class B** view or when popping back to it from another one that it has pushed.

I followed a suggestion in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642312/ about overriding `UINavigationController` and I made some custom delegate methods, one is called right after `[super popViewControllerAnimated:]`. My subclass is available at https://gist.github.com/jpmhouston/6118713 and delegate method is:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController isPoppingViewController:(UIViewController *)poppedViewController backTo:(UIViewController *)revealedViewController {
    if (revealedViewController == self && [poppedViewController isKindOfClass:[MyClassB class]]) {
        [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        // ...and more code to run only when going from class B back to class A
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are simpler ways to have `setNavigationBarHidden:` called following the Back button being pressed, but this worked for me.