# Wired black space under screen when pop to previous view controller using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using `UINavigationController` to direct some view `controllers`.In some view controller, I don't want to use `UINavigationBar`, but in some others i may use. Now I am try to pop one view controller using `UINavigationBar` to its previous one which hide `UINavigationBar`. But when poped, there is one wired black space under screen. After you rotate the screen, the space will disappear.

the normal view controller A should be like this:

[image]

when press the text button, a view controller B will be pushed, which is as followings:
[image]

when click back button on the navigation bar. A will come out.but there is a black space at the bottom.

[image]

If rotate the screen, the space will disappear. And also in A's `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method i hide the navigationbar and let the screen autorotate.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];
}
```

whats wrong with this situation? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `setNavigationBarHidden:` method in the back button action method. it works. If i add this method in `viewWillDisappear:` method or others, it seems it doesn't work. The navigation bar will have effect on next appear view controller. which means, there will be a black space in the next view controller in the navigation stack.

Finally, i add a action method for the back button and `setNavigationBarHidden:YES` in the method, which is as follows:

```
- (void)backBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you were to pop using animation, I found it better to reverse the order of those calls, calling `setNavigationBarHidden` after `popViewControllerAnimated:`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028074/